# Segregate Array base on Months

Tags: php

I want to segregate an array based on months.

Here is a sample of an array and the output I wish to get:

```
Array
{
    [1] => 1:"Fruit";
    [2] => 2:"Mangoe"; 
    [3] => 3:"2015-2-5";
}

Array
{
    [1] => 1:"Fruit";
    [2] => 2:"Banana";
    [3] => 3:"2015-4-11";
}

Array
{
    [1] => 1:"Fruit";
    [2] => 2:"Orange"; 
    [3] => 3:"2015-2-10";
}

Array
{
    [1] => 1:"Fruit";
    [2] => 2:"Pineapple";
    [3] => 3:"2015-8-3";
}
```

Target Output:

```
February
Fruit:Banana
Fruit:Orange

April
Fruit:Banana

August
Fruit:Pineapple
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

    foreach ($results as $key => $value) 
    {
        $value = get_object_vars($value);
        $raw_slice = explode('s:', $value['rawdata']);


        //VARIABLES
        //GET TITLE
        $title_cut = explode(':"', str_replace('";', '', $raw_slice[2]));
        $title = $title_cut['1'];

        //GET DATE
        $date_cut = explode(':"', str_replace('";', '', $raw_slice[3]));
        $date_text = $date_cut['1'];



        $month = "01";
        $year = "2015";

        $start_date = "01-".$month."-".$year;
        $start_time = strtotime($start_date);

        $end_time = strtotime("+1 month", $start_time);

        for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
        {
           $list[] = date('Y-m-d-D', $i);
        }


        echo "<pre>";

        echo "<div class ='title'>";
        echo $title.'<br>';
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class ='date'>";
        echo date('F \ j,\ Y',strtotime($date_text));
        echo "</div>";


        echo "</pre>";        
    }

?>
```

Comment: Where is the mango in your expected output?

Comment: How is this array being created? Seems like you could make your life a lot easier if you created the arrays differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange array and if possible, you'd do well to restructure it. Not sure how it's being built. But if that's all you have to work with, here's one way to get the output you want:

```
$arrays = array
(
    array
    (
        1 => '1:"Fruit"',
        2 => '2:"Mangoe"', 
        3 => '3:"2015-2-5"',
    ),
    array
    (
        1 => '1:"Fruit"',
        2 => '2:"Banana"',
        3 => '3:"2015-4-11"',
    ),
    array
    (
        1 => '1:"Fruit"',
        2 => '2:"Orange"', 
        3 => '3:"2015-2-10"',
    ),
    array
    (
        1 => '1:"Fruit"',
        2 => '2:"Pineapple"',
        3 => '3:"2015-8-3"',
    ),
);
$months = array();
foreach($arrays as $a)
{
    preg_match('/\"([^\"]*?)\"/', $a[1], $category);
    preg_match('/\"([^\"]*?)\"/', $a[2], $item);
    preg_match('/\"([^\"]*?)\"/', $a[3], $date);
    list($Y,$M,$D) = explode('-', str_replace('"', '', $date[0]));
    $M = str_pad($M, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $D = str_pad($D, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $unix = strtotime($Y.'-'.$M.'-'.$D);
    $key = date('m', $unix);
    $months[$key]['month'] = date('F', $unix);
    $months[$key]['categories'][str_replace('"', '', $category[0])][] = str_replace('"', '', $item[0]);
}
ksort($months);
echo '<pre>';
foreach($months as $m)
{
    echo "<div class ='month'>";
    echo $m['month'];
    echo "</div>";
    ksort($m['categories']);
    foreach($m['categories'] as $cat => $items)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)        
        {
            echo "<div class ='item'>";
            echo $cat.':'.$item;
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
echo '</pre>';
```